# Angularfire set does not return a $promise

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Granted, I just started with AngularFire and Firebase, but, it seems quite transparent, and well documented.
Yet, there's one thing that doesn't make sense to me;

AngularFire has a $set function you can use to set values in the backend storage. From what I've read, in version 1.0.0 they deprecated this function, and it is now just "set" (without the $ sign).
Difference seems to me that $set used to return a promise object, so one could chain functions, where as the new set function returns nothing it seems...

For instance, when I have this code:

```
function createprofile(authData, user){
  return fbutil.ref('profiles/'+authData.uid).set({ 
    firstname: user.firstname, 
    lastname: user.lastname 
  });
};
```

And my fbutil.ref function is as follows:

```
function firebaseRef(path) {
  var ref = new $window.Firebase(FB_BASEURL);
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  if( args.length ) {
    ref = ref.child(pathRef(args));
  }
  return ref;
}
```

How can I do something with the "createprofile"'s return value? At the moment, it's always "undefined". I was hoping I could just chain after a "set" function to make sure it actually worked before doing something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't called AngularFire set (there is [no method by this name](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html) in any AngularFire service, as you've noted). You've called [set() using the Firebase SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html), which does not return a promise, but expects you to pass in a callback. Brushing up on [fundamentals of writing data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html) would help here.

```
function createprofile(authData, user){
  var def = $q.defer();
  fbutil.ref('profiles/'+authData.uid).set({ 
    firstname: user.firstname, 
    lastname: user.lastname 
  }, function(err) {
    if( err ) { def.reject(err); }
    else { def.resolve(); }
  });
  return def.promise;
};
```

Internally, AngularFire uses a [makeNodeResolver() utility](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/utils.js#L255) to convert callbacks to promises. You could use that as [an example](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseArray.js#L114) of the above approach.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll look through them to get a better understanding of how it all works internally.  
And, using a deferred does indeed work, I thought of doing that, but thought I'd ask first as there might be something angularfire provided out of the box.  
  
By the way, I will accept your answer, cause, obviously it works, but I think you should return the promise object, not the function (so, return def.promise in stead of def.promise()), you might want to edit that into your answer.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I mix up def.promise and def.promise() ten times a week. Wish they would just agree.